# How to SSH to a SLURM scheduler and execute SLURM commands using a Python script rather than the CMD to run a Python script?

Tags: python, linux, ssh, slurm, sbatch

Currently I am connecting to the SLURM scheduler and running the requested SLURM commands (such as `sbatch` and `squeue`) in the following manner (using Ubuntu 22.04):

- SSH to the SLURM job scheduler using the necessary credentials in the CMD
- Submit the SLURM command `sbatch mysbatchscript.sh`
- Any other SLURM commands such as `squeue` are also submitted in the CMD as done previously

At the end of this sbatch script called *mysbatchscript.sh* I also have the line `python3 main_deeplearning.py` . The aim of this sbatch script is to run a deep learning model using CUDA.

My questions are as follows;

- Is there a way how I can initiate the SSH connection and also be able to run those SLURM commands in the same Python script rather than keep using the CMD?
- When executing the SLURM command `sbatch mysbatchscript.sh` I would also like to pass arguments found in my Python script. Is it possible that the sbatch command accepts Python arguments i.e. `sbatch mysbatchscript.sh arg1 arg2` where `arg1` and `arg2` are input arguments to a deep learning model found in the main_deeplearning.py Python script?

The only Python module that I found that comes close to interacting with the SLURM scheduler is called Pyslurm but I do not know how to connect this to the SSH connection which has to be done prior to using the Pyslurm methods and I do not know how to connect this to the SLURM job scheduler.

Thus, up to now I kept using the 'traditional' method of connecting to SSH and running the SLURM commands such as `sbatch` and `squeue` through the Ubuntu terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `paramiko` library in Python to do this from your local machine.

In general, your script can look like this and execute whatever is on client side:

```
import paramiko
import getpass
import time


password = getpass.getpass('Enter your password: ')

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('servername', username='<your_username>', password=password)
```

From this you can submit sbatch files by knowing the path on the server. This can be done like so:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('sbatch path_to_script.job')
job_id = int(stdout.read().decode().split()[-1])
print(f'Submitted job with ID {job_id}')
```